# How to add database field in table dynamically using MVC and Entity Framework using .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am developing a .Net application and I have Database available. 
I have a category class like :

```
public partial class Category
{
   public int CategoryId {get;set;}
   public string CategoryName {get;set;}
}
```

How can I add dynamic fields to this model and hence to the database? if not possible then is there any other way to fulfill my problem?

I am allowing the user to add his desired custom fields to be added. So, my database schema becomes

Category(CategoryId, CategoryName, CustomField1, CustomField2);

How can I do this using EF 5 and MVC ? Or is there any other way we can do it ?

Comment: Can you give more details behind why you would want to dynamically add these CustomFields? I'm thinking there may be a better way to accomplish this than adding database fields on the fly like this.

Comment: You would need to basically recompile at runtime (somehow) the entire managed module which loaded the EF model after adding the fields. It might be possible but is entirely not practical.

Comment: I would suggest adding a list to your `Category` class, which is like a list of objects called `CustomField` and just add more to that list.  So in your DB you would have a `CustomFields` table relating to `Category`

Comment: It is not right approach (idea in question)

Comment: I want to provide the functionality to user to add some custom field like as vTiger (https://www.vtiger.com/) application. i have shown that some CRM tools provide user to add custom field on the fly to database and display on the add/edit and list page.

Eg.

we have a product module and in the module we have just provide below field 1. Product Name 2. Product Type 3. Product Price

Now user want to add another filed in product module as per it's requirement like 1. Product Category 2. Product Description

Answer (score 5):

Going to add this suggestion as an answer, as I don't think dynamically adding columns to the database is the best idea.

In your `Category` class, add in a list of another type, lets call it `CustomField`. When you allow a user to add a new field, just stick it in this list

```
public partial class Category
{
   public int CategoryId {get;set;}
   public string CategoryName {get;set;}
   public IList<CustomField> CustomFields {get;set;}
}

public class CustomField
{
   public int CustomFieldId {get;set;}

   public string FieldName {get;set;}
   public string FieldValue {get;set;}

   [ForeignKey("Category")]
   public int CategoryId {get;set;}
   public Category Category {get;set;}
}
```